# Keep only rows if the count of an object is maximum

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame as follows

```
A B
1 2
1 2
1 0
1 2
2 3
2 3
2 1
3 0
3 0
3 1
3 2
```

I would like to get the following output

```
A B
1 2
1 2
1 2
2 3
2 3
3 0
3 0
```

This means that I need only rows where the count of A is maximum. Is there any solution to this?

Many thanks!

Comment: could You elaborate on what You mean by _maximum_? also please provide [mre]

Comment: why 3 2 was deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `groupby()` with [`Series.mode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html#pandas-series-mode):

```
df_out = df[df.groupby("A")["B"].transform(lambda x: x == x.mode()[0])]
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  2
3  1  2
4  2  3
5  2  3
7  3  0
8  3  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
df.set_index(['A','B']).loc[df.groupby(['A','B']).size().groupby(level=0).idxmax()].reset_index()
```